# How to merge textview

Tags: android, layout

Hi guys Thanks for previous comments and answers. I have two different attributes in XML form. one is Imageview and another is Textview. I want to show both like table layout formate. also i tried table layout but the text in the textview not fit in the margin. It only display some part of text, the rest will disappear. I dont know how to do this.. can anyone guide me how to rectify this solution.

Comment: Use LinearLayout with android:layout_weight. check [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)

Comment: can u post ur screen to be made?